# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list / Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, key-value

I have `custom_comissionData.ProviderID_{parent.customData.serviceLogo}.fix`

where parent.customData.serviceLogo is another variable, which value I want to put here as part of variable name.

I mean `parent.customData.serviceLogo= 1000`

and I want to get value of

```
custom_comissionData.ProviderID_1000.fix
```

but the way I typed it causes "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Any way to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are equivalent in JavaScript:

```
object.property
object['property']
```

You may access your item using the second approach:

```
custom_comissionData['ProviderID_' + parent.customData.serviceLogo].fix
```

Comment: `object.property` and `object['property']` are equal, but I think you have hit spot on what OP is asking!

Comment: @dev-null Oh, yes, of course. Edited the answer :) Thank you